# Spring JPA Projection not working with UUID types?

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jpa, kotlin

I have a project with Kotlin and Springboot.
In this project an entity have this following fields: `id`, `name` and `parent`. 
What i want is to only get the `id` and the `name`. So i made a projection interface view for that entity.

This is my entity:

```
@Entity
data class Keyword(

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    var id: UUID? = null,

    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    var parent: UUID? = null,

    @NotBlank
    var name: String? = null

)
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
interface KeywordRepository: JpaRepository<Keyword, UUID> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT keyword.id, keyword.parent, keyword.name FROM keyword LEFT JOIN project_keyword ON project_keyword.keyword_id = keyword.id WHERE project_keyword.project_id LIKE :id", nativeQuery = true)
    fun findAllKeywordsByProjectId(id: UUID): MutableList<KeyWordView>
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
class KeywordService (
  private val projectService: ProjectService,
  private val keywordRepository: KeywordRepository
) {

    fun getKeywordsByProjectId(id: UUID): MutableList<KeyWordView> {

        projectService.checkIfProjectExistsById(id)

        return keywordRepository.findAllKeywordsByProjectId(id).toMutableList()
    }
}
```

My projection interface class:

```
interface KeyWordView {

    val id: UUID

    val name: String?
}
```

When i call this endpoint via controller class. I get this output:

```
 "list": [
      {
        "name": "MARINE MICROBIOTA",
        "id": "0,31,-36,77,29,123,66,-25,-127,-43,-31,83,104,-90,47,10"
      }
    ]
```

But if i change the `val id: String` to `val id: UUID` in my `KeywordView` interface, i get this following error:

```
{
  "code": 500,
  "data": null,
  "message": "Could not write JSON: Projection type must be an interface!; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Projection type must be an interface! (through reference chain: no.inmeta.ris.util.response.ResponseDto[\"data\"]->no.inmeta.ris.util.pagination.PageDto[\"list\"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.sun.proxy.$Proxy199[\"id\"])",
  "status": "FAIL"
}
```

Anyone know how to solve this problem? I want to receive the UUID as UUID not with the strange format.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is the UUID Class. As your entity states you defined dir hibernate that the column in db is a binary(16). And i suppose using this UUID Type in the Interface projection does not Work since there is no valid mapping information (how to transform the data coming as binary with a length of 16 bytes to the UUID Class). So I assume you have to change the Type of your column or you have to use string and write a function to Transform that String.

Another possibility is to create a second entity for that table with Just the two cols you want. And Just use that second dao as your are using yiur projection.